# How can I implement PEPPOL in my project and please tell me step by step

Tags: asp.net, peppol

How can I implement PEPPOL in my project and please tell me step by step.

How can I implement PEPPOL(E-Invoicing) in my project and please tell me step by step.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is way to broad. Same as asking how can I implement AS2 in my organization or X.400 or 'how can I use java'... or...

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without more detailed information
Eg which ERP / procurement system, amount of invoices to send per day

We are using our provider for e-invoicing to customers this includes mapping to UBL, validating, signing, forwarding, error reporting etc